# Create flutter library to support both web and mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-html, flutter-web

I need to create a library which implements a data persistence which should work across mobile and web. For web, I need to `import 'dart:html'` and for mobile I would use shared preferences.

Problem is, the project won't compile for mobile if "dart:html" is imported. Does there exist a way around for this? Maybe I could have conditional imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can load different handlers by judging   (I support you writing this library)

```dart
import '_network_image_io.dart' if (dart.library.html) '_network_image_web.dart' as network_image;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Once I find some free time I'd love to write a package around this.